# How to use object from class A in class B?

Tags: python, overriding, maya

i have [Class Basic] and [Class squash]. then i wanna use 'LWheel01Con'controller created in [Class Basic]. i really dont know how to do it!! please help me ;( im very beginner of python, so plz explain easily of show your fixed code. thank you very much.)

p.s) the lines that not important to fix this issue are deleted. and plz ignore the wrong indentation.

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from ..base import control

class Basic(object):

def __init__(self,prefix='car',rigScale=1.0):

    MJ = self.basic_module_jnt(prefix+'_basic')

    WC = self.basic_wheel_con(MJ['LeftWheelJnt'],MJ['RightWheelJnt'],rigScale, MJ['rigmodule'] )


def basic_wheel_con(self, LeftWheelJnt,RightWheelJnt,rigScale, rigmodule ):

    #wheel con
    **LWheel01Con **= control.Control(translateTo=LeftWheelJnt[0] ,rotateTo = LeftWheelJnt[0], detailName = LeftWheelJnt[0][:-4], scale = rigScale*3,  parent = rigmodule.controlsGrp, shape = 'circle'+'X', twoOffset=1)        
    LWheel02Con = control.Control(translateTo=LeftWheelJnt[1] ,rotateTo = LeftWheelJnt[1], detailName = LeftWheelJnt[1][:-4], scale = rigScale*3,  parent = rigmodule.controlsGrp, shape = 'circle'+'X', twoOffset=1)
    RWheel01Con = control.Control(translateTo=RightWheelJnt[0] ,rotateTo = RightWheelJnt[0], detailName = RightWheelJnt[0][:-4],scale = rigScale*3,  parent = rigmodule.controlsGrp, shape = 'circle'+'X', twoOffset=1)        
    RWheel02Con = control.Control(translateTo=RightWheelJnt[1] ,rotateTo = RightWheelJnt[1], detailName = RightWheelJnt[1][:-4],scale = rigScale*3,  parent = rigmodule.controlsGrp, shape = 'circle'+'X', twoOffset=1)
   
    return_dick = {'LWheel01Con':LWheel01Con,'LWheel02Con':LWheel02Con,'RWheel01Con':RWheel01Con,'RWheel02Con':RWheel02Con }
    return return_dick
```

---

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import pymel.core as pm
from ..base import control
from . import basic

class Squash(basic.Basic):
    def __init__(self, prefix='car',rigScale=1.0):
    
    MJ = super(Squash,self).basic_module_jnt(prefix+'_squash')

    self.squash_all(MJ['LeftWheelJnt'],rigScale,prefix,MJ['leftFrontJntPos'],MJ['rigmodule'])



def squash_all(self,LeftWheelJnt,rigScale,prefix,leftFrontJntPos,rigmodule):

        #create lattice
    tireMesh = ['FL_Tyre_Floor','FB_Tyre_Floor'] 

    #creat BS mesh
    tireBS = mc.duplicate(tireMesh[0],n=tireMesh[0]+'_BS')
    mc.parent(tireBS, w=1)
    mc.select(tireBS)
    CreateLattice = mc.lattice( divisions = (5,10,10), commonParent = 1, objectCentered = 1,n=tireMesh[0]+'_')  
    LatticeGrp = tireMesh[0]+'_LatticeGroup'      
    mc.parentConstraint(LeftWheelJnt[0], tireBS[0], mo=1)
    mc.move(leftFrontJntPos[0], leftFrontJntPos[1], leftFrontJntPos[2], LatticeGrp+'.rotatePivot', rotatePivotRelative=1)
    mc.move(leftFrontJntPos[0], leftFrontJntPos[1], leftFrontJntPos[2], LatticeGrp+'.scalePivot', rotatePivotRelative=1)
    
    #Lattice point edit
    lattice = pm.PyNode(tireMesh[0]+'_Lattice')
    numOfRowsU = lattice.uDivisions.get()

    for row in range(numOfRowsU):
        latPoints = lattice.pt[0:4][0][row]
        pm.move(latPoints, (0,0.8,0), r=1) 

    #create squash Con
    squashCon = control.Control(translateTo=LeftWheelJnt[0] ,rotateTo = LeftWheelJnt[0], detailName = LeftWheelJnt[0][:-4]+'_squash',
                        scale = rigScale*0.5, shape = 'switch', twoOffset=1) 
    mc.transformLimits(squashCon.C, ty= (0, 1) ,ety= (1, 1)) #enableTranslationY:turn on (min,max) limit// ty:range of limit
    mc.move(-rigScale*2,-3,0,squashCon.C+'.cv[*]', r=1,os=1,worldSpaceDistance=1)  
    mc.rotate(0,0,90,squashCon.C+'.cv[*]')   
    
    #constraints
    mc.pointConstraint(**'l_wheel_01_con'**, squashCon.Off2) ** #I want to use LWheel01Con from Class basic instead of 'l_wheel_01_con'**
```

Comment: As far as I can see you never call basic_wheel_con, so there is never any LWheel01Con to use.

Comment: yes.i knew about it, but when i call the [def basic_wheel_con] in Class Squash, all of that 'basic_wheel_con' method is executed(like create controllers..)  i just want to get 'LWheel01Con' in Class Squash, not to execute all of that method again... it there any way to do it??

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know inheritance works more like this in python:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("initA")
        self.bla()
    def bla(self):
        self.x = 123
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("initB")
        print(self.x)
    
b = B()
```

In your case the **init**() of basic class is never called.

Comment: if i call __init__ method of Class Basic to Class Squash,

Comment: Yeah, I think this is why my answer did not work.

Comment: sorry. I didn;t ended up the reply. here is my question again. if i call the __init__ of Class basic to Class Squash, in __init__ , lots of method executing some code somthings like [self.basic_module_jnt(prefix+'_basic')] and so on.. then when i execute Class Squash, __init__ of Class Basic will be executed that i dont want to. that is problem also

Comment: If you do not want to execute the init function of the inherited class, you should maybe change your class design a bit so that the construction is more reliable.

Comment: OK. i will change all of the the structure of coding that def __init__ has only self.attribute not another mothod. thank you very much!